# How can i fix my code to split a given sum into k numbers in all its combinations

Tags: java, sum, numbers, combinations, sequences

I am having a problem with my code. I need it to give me a sequence of numbers for any given number(the sum of the sequence will be the given number). Currently my program has 2 operations in its input. The first being the number and the second being the maximum number which will appear in the output sequence.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        partition(n, max, "");
    }
    public static void partition(int n, int max, String prefix) {
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = Math.min(max, n); i >= 1; i--) {
            partition(n-i, i, prefix + " " + i);
        }
    }
```

Example: 
now i have this output:
`n= 6, max =6
 *  6
 *  5 1
 *  4 2
 *  4 1 1
 *  3 3
 *  3 2 1
 *  3 1 1 1
 *  2 2 2
 *  2 2 1 1
 *  2 1 1 1 1
 *  1 1 1 1 1 1`

But i want something like this:
`n=2, k=3
002
020
200
011
101
110`

Comment: These are permutations. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218019/generating-permutations-of-an-int-array-using-java-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating permutations of an int array using java -- error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218019/generating-permutations-of-an-int-array-using-java-error)

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter in what order the permutations appear?  If not, you are **very close**.  All you have to do is change your `max` input to `k`, allow `i=0` in your loop, and cover the remaining base cases.

```
public static void partition(int n, int k, String prefix) {
    if (k == 0 && n == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
        return;
    }
    if (k < 0 || n < 0) return;

    for (int i = n; i >= 0; --i) {
        partition(n-i, k-1, prefix + " " + i);
    }
}
```