# what is the algorithm for iterating over all possible variations of an array?

Tags: algorithm

for example there is an array [1, 3, 5, 7], the algorithm should give all its variations. Array can be any size. I thought to implement this using recursive permutations, but nothing adequate came to my mind.
 `[1, 3, 7, 5], [1, 5, 3, 7], [1, 5, 7, 3], [1, 7, 3, 5], [1, 7, 5, 3] and so on`

Comment: Understand, that's going to get out of hand very quickly. There are `n!` permutations. An array of length 4 has 24 possible permutations. There are 479,001,600 possible permutations with an array of 12 items. This topic has been covered quite well here.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13218019/56778

Answer (score 0):

just loop over all values, just exclude ones already used, like this:

```js
function* generatePermutations(a) {
  function* recPermutations(a, r) {
    for (const e of a) {
      if (!r.includes(e)) {
        r.push(e);

        if (r.length == a.length)
          yield r;
        else
          yield * recPermutations(a, r);

        r.pop();
      }
    }
  }

  yield * recPermutations(a, []);
}

const it = generatePermutations([1,3,5,7]);
for (const i of it)
  console.log(i.toString());
```